# Pulling "Now Playing" data from html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a shoutcast server that displays info on this page:
http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/

I am trying to pull the "Now Playing" data from this page and display it on my website that is playing the stream through a player.

Clicking on the song title and following this link:

http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/currentsong?sid=1

Shows the current song in plain text...
So I'm wondering if there is a javascript or php script I can use to scrape this data to display it in my player?

I've tried AJAX but got cross domain errors and YQL gives me an error of "Invalid URL http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/currentsong?sid=1: Invalid HTTP destination port"

I was wondering if there was anyone out there with a better idea to solve this issue?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you considered calling a local PHP script with AJAX? The PHP script can do a CURL to get the and pass it back without cross domain issues.

Comment: I don't actually have access to the server to place a script to curl the information.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match()` in PHP,
but it's a bit difficult because this page only 
shows the artist name, song, then album(I presume?),
and the only way to separate these would be the " " or "-".
Some songs might have a "-" in them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not actually looking for a method to parse it, I'm looking for a method to pull the information off of that page, and pass it to my website do display accordingly.